# AdMob SDK on Android: multiple SCHTimer Threads after showing Ads

Tags: java, android, admob

I am using Google AdMob for showing Ads in an application of mine. Everything is working fine, unless that the number of Threads add up over time. My application will get more and more DaemonThreads named "SCHTimer" that are created internally by AdMob.

It is the same problem as this guy has: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-admob-ads-sdk/EvfESpBSjbY/DEyCfxP4hxcJ
Unfortunately, there is no answer to it on the forum. My AdMob initializion/destroying looks very similar. After debugging with several breakpoints, I can verify that the destroy part gets called.

Also I couldn't find any indication of leaking objects in the HPROF profile.

Therefore, I am running out of ideas, what else to look for. Did anyone else experience this problem? (How) Did you solve it?

[image: Debug view of all running Threads]

Comment: I see the same issue. But no solution yet.